# Average from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT p.NAME, r.DATE, c.NAME, SUM(hs.result), SUM(h.par), (SUM(hs.result) - SUM(h.par)) AS "Score"
 FROM hole_scores hs
 JOIN players p ON hs.player_id = p.id
 JOIN rounds r ON r.id = hs.session_id
 JOIN holes h ON h.id = hs.hole_id 
 JOIN courses c ON c.id = r.course_id
 GROUP BY p.NAME, r.id
 ORDER BY Score ASC
```

The query gives me this result (first rows):

```
 NAME       DATE        NAME        SUM(hs.result)  SUM(h.par)  Score
Player 1    29.7.2014   Course 1    50              57          -7
Player 2    7.6.2014    Course 2    48              54          -6
Player 1    22.5.2014   Course 1    51              57          -6
Player 3    6.6.2014    Course 1    52              57          -5
Player 1    19.8.2013   Course 1    53              57          -4
Player 4    1.9.2011    Course 1    56              59          -3
Player 5    15.10.2011  Course 1    56              59          -3
Player 4    2.8.2013    Course 1    54              57          -3
Player 1    3.6.2014    Course 1    54              57          -3
Player 6    8.7.2014    Course 1    54              57          -3
Player 4    16.7.2014   Course 1    54              57          -3
Player 1    21.4.2015   Course 1    53              56          -3
Player 2    23.6.2012   Course 2    52              54          -2
```

How would I get average of each player scores?

Comment: How would you like the average displayed? In another column in this query? Or using another query?

Comment: All I really need is the player name and average of hes/her scores, so it could be in a other query.

Comment: So... group by p.NAME and use [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) : avg(hs.result - h.par) ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but if I add (SELECT AVG(Score)) and GROUP BY p.NAME I get error: Error Code: 1247. Reference 'Score' not supported (reference to group function)

Comment: You can improve the quality of your Question by editing it to include a table of sample desired output that is based on the sample data provided.  I also recommend that you replace `ORDER BY Score` with `ORDER BY players.id` so it becomes clear in your sample data that we have all records for the sample players available.  Finally, you should replace `GROUP BY players.NAME` with `GROUP BY players.id`, otherwise the results of two players with the same name (such as `John Smith`) will be merged together.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will try to make my questions better in the future! And yes, it is better to use id to identify players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT players.id AS player_id,
       players.name AS player_name,
       AVG( Score ) AS avg_score
FROM ( SELECT hole_scores.player_id AS player_id,
              ( SUM( hole_scores.result ) - SUM( holes.par ) ) AS Score
       FROM hole_scores
       JOIN holes ON holes.id = hole_scores.hole_id
       JOIN rounds ON rounds.id = hole_scores.session_id
       GROUP BY hole_scores.player_id,
                rounds.id
     ) AS scoreFinder
JOIN players ON players.id = scoreFinder.player_id
GROUP BY players.id
ORDER BY player_name,
         player_id;
```

This statement uses a subquery based on a reduced version of your supplied statement to find the scores for each `player` *for each* `round`.

Note that normally `name` can not be safely assumed to be unique as it is normally *possible*, even if it is not normally the case, that two `players` *can* have the same `name`.  As such I have chosen the `id` value to uniquely identify each `player`.  Since this value can be found in `hole_scores.player_id` there is no need to join with `players` at this stage.

It then performs an `INNER JOIN` between the subquery's results and `players` so that the `name` of each `player` may be included in the results.  I chose to join with `players` at this stage rather than in the subquery as the *results* of the subquery will have only one record for each `player` to join to rather than potentially many for each player in the subquery's source dataset.  I hope that this will make the statement slightly more efficient.

The statement then groups the joined dataset's records by the unique identifier for each player, and returns the `id` and `name` values for each `player` along with the average value of their `Score` at the end of each `round`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Exactly what I wanted! I tried to use subquery myself, but couldn't get it right. So much to learn! And yes, it is better to use id to identify players although I have no players with same name in my data at the moment. This will help a lot with other quries too in my current project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average, I think you can do:

```
SELECT p.NAME, (SUM(hs.result) - SUM(h.par))/COUNT(*) AS "Score"
FROM hole_scores hs JOIN
     players p
     ON hs.player_id = p.id JOIN
     rounds r
     ON r.id = hs.session_id JOIN
     holes h
     ON h.id = hs.hole_id JOIN
     courses c
     ON c.id = r.course_id
GROUP BY p.NAME
ORDER BY Score ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't give correct data. I think I will work around this by exporting my data to pandas dataframe and get average from there.